# Flex 4 change popup's overlay color

Tags: flex4

How can I change the color or the transparency of the popup's overlay? I want to have another color and alpha 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://mprami.wordpress.com/2008/04/22/alert_popup_modal_transparancy_color_blur_changes/

In flex ‘’ tag has mainly four attributes related to modal properties of pop-ups.

- modalTransparency
- modalTransparencyBlur
- modalTransparencyColor
- modalTransparencyDuration

In spark it looks like these were renamed slightly:

- modal-transparency
- modal-transparency-color
- modal-transparency-duration
- modal-transparency-blur (guessing on this one)

Comment: In a spark Application these parameters don't seem to be available

Answer (score 1):

To extend on artjumble's answer, if you're using a css file, you can also declare it like that in the css file:

```
global {
    modalTransparencyBlur: 0;
    modalTransparency: 0.3;
    modalTransparencyColor: black;
    modalTransparencyDuration: 500;
}
```